# Disjoint Events iff $P(A \cap B) = 0$

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

I found for example [here](https://www.rapidtables.com/math/probability/basic_probability.html) that:
$A$ and $B$ are disjoint iff $P(A\cap B) == 0$.
I don't understand why.

Take for example:

$A = \{$"rolling a six-sided dice a 7 shows up"$\}$

$B = \{"$rolling a six-sided dice a 7 shows up"$\}$

A and B are not disjoint, yet $P(A\cap B) = 0$ holds. 
Where am I wrong?

Edit: A better example (Thanks to Gerry Myerson):

$C = \{$"choosing 1/2  from a uniform random distribution [0,1]"$\}$

$D = \{"$choosing 1/2 from a uniform random distribution [0,1]"$\}$

C and D are not disjoint, yet $P(C\cap D) = 0$ holds.

Comment: Your $A$ and $B$ are both empty, so they are certainly disjoint.

Comment: A={7} how is that empty?

Comment: Perhaps a better example would be, $A$ is choosing $1/2$ uniformly at random from $[0,1]$, and $B$ is the same.

Comment: 7 is not in the sample space for rolling a die.

Comment: Okay. My Professor just told us that sample spaces can always be "too large", containing arbitrary events with the probability 0 ...?!

Comment: Fine. But then you have to say what the smaple space is, so people will know what you're talking about. Anyway, one way or another, the statement on that website is nonsense.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the formula is wrong in general.

Just take any Event $A \neq \emptyset$ with a $P$-measure of zero. Then $A \cap \Omega = A \neq \emptyset$ but $P(A \cap \Omega) = P(A) = 0$.

However, if you have a probability space without nonempty sets with measure zero, i.e. for all events $A$ one has $A = \emptyset \iff P(A) = 0$, the formula is clearly true.